# How to find a substring in an array of strings in matlab?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, find

I have a string `'ADSL'`. I want to find this string in an array of strings `char('PSTN,ADSL','ADSL,VDSL','FTTH,VDSL')`

when i run this command

```
strmatch('ADSL',char('PSTN,ADSL','ADSL,VDSL','FTTH,VDSL'));
```

the output is `2`
But I expect the output as `[1 2]`

strmatch only gives positive result if the search string appears at the begining of row.

How can I find the search string if it occurs anywhere in the row?

Comment: If you have a cell array of strings, try strfind with cellfun as follows: cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) strfind(x,'ADSL'),a,'UniformOutput',false))

Answer (score 3):

Given the following input:

```
array = {'PSTN,ADSL', 'ADSL,VDSL', 'FTTH,VDSL'};
str = 'ADSL';
```

We find the starting position of each string match using:

```
>> pos = strfind(array, str)
pos = 
    [6]    [1]    []
```

or

```
>> pos = regexp(array, str)
pos = 
    [6]    [1]    []
```

We can then find the indices of matching strings using:

```
>> matches = find(~cellfun(@isempty,pos))
matches =
     1     2
```

Comment: `cellfun('isempty', ...)` may be faster than `cellfun(@isempty, ...)`

Comment: yes I think it is, though the difference is getting smaller: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost (see the comments as well)

Answer (score 1):

For an array of strings, it's better to use a cell array. That way strings can be of differnet lengths (and `regexp` can be applied on all cells at once):

```
cellArray = {'PSTN,ADSL','ADSL,VDSL','FTTH,VDSL'};
str = 'ADSL';
```

Then:

```
result = find(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(cellArray, str)));
```

will give what you want.

If you really have a char array as in your example,

```
array = char('PSTN,ADSL','ADSL,VDSL','FTTH,VDSL');
```

you can convert to a cell array (with `cellstr`) and apply the above:

```
result = find(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(cellstr(array), str)));
```

Comment: the conversion from char-matrix to cell array of strings can be simplified using `cellstr`

Answer (score 0):

i would use strfind

```
a=strfind(cellstr(char('PSTN,ADSL','ADSL,VDSL','FTTH,VDSL')),'ADSL');
```

in this case will be a three by one cell array containing the index where you string starts at in the corresponding string